# Trying to simplify a regular expression of which I currently have an abominably long one

Tags: regular-language, regular-expressions

I have a pretty simple question, but I don't know how to simplify this regular expression further from the answer that I have. I'd like to find a regular expression for the set of strings over `{x,y,z}` that have precisely two `x` (no need to be together) and one `y`.

The answer that I have is a really long one that basically is the union of all the possible concatenable combinations, but it just feels dumb.

What am I missing? How do you show the regular expression for 3 `(x,x,y)` things that have to be there but in no particular order, with `c*`?

Comment: Can you draw a state machine for that (I found one with six states)? And have you learned how to convert a state machine to a RE?

Comment: I don't think I've heard of a machine state, sorry, could you briefly explain how that relates to what I'm looking for?

Comment: A finite state machine is like a turing machine that can only read the tape, and only move one way: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine

Comment: For every FSM, there's a RE that encodes the words it accepts, and vice-versa. But since you haven't met that yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start with the 'union' you've come up with, eg

$(\ (x|y|z)^*y(x|y|z)^*x(x|y|z)^*x(x|y|z)^*\ |\  (x|y|z)^*x(x|y|z)^*y(x|y|z)^*x(x|y|z)^*\ |\  (x|y|z)^*x(x|y|z)^*x(x|y|z)^*y(x|y|z)^*\ )$,

In human English, this might be read:

- any number of anything, then a $y$, then any number of anything, then an $x$, then any number of anything, then an $x$, then any number of anything
- OR: any number of anything, then an $x$, then any number of anything, then a $y$, then any number of anything, then an $x$, then any number of anything
- OR: any number of anything, then an $x$, then any number of anything, then an $x$, then any number of anything, then a $y$, then any number of anything

and then simplify it by factoring out the common prefix and suffix:

$(x|y|z)^*\ (\ y(x|y|z)^*x(x|y|z)^*x\ |\ x(x|y|z)^*y(x|y|z)^*x\ |\ x(x|y|z)^*x(x|y|z)^*y\ )\ (x|y|z)^*$.

In human English, this means:

- Any number of anything, THEN
- - a $y$, then any number of anything, then an $x$, then any number of anything, then an $x$
- - OR an $x$, then any number of anything, then a $y$, then any number of anything, then an $x$
- - OR an $x$, then any number of anything, then an $x$, then any number of anything, then a $y$
- THEN, any number of anything

You can simplify this further with more factoring out of common prefixes and suffixes:

$(x|y|z)^*\ (\ y(x|y|z)^*x(x|y|z)^*x\ |\ x(x|y|z)^*\ (\ y(x|y|z)^*x\ |\ x(x|y|z)^*y\ )\ )\ (x|y|z)^*$.

Again, translating into human, this means:

- Any number of anything, THEN
- - a $y$, then any number of anything, then an $x$, then any number of anything, then an $x$
- - OR an $x$, then any number of anything, THEN
- - - a $y$, then any number of anything, then an $x$
- - - OR an $x$, then any number of anything, then a $y$,
- THEN, any number of anything

Comment: Yeah, I guess there really isn't a shorter way of doing this given the available properties. Either way, thanks for pointing out the right+left distributive property over union of sets, I didn't think that was possible.

Comment: You're welcome. Yep, RE's (and FSM's) can't count. For things like "the set of strings with more x's than y's" you need more powerful languages such as a context-free grammar.